# Include JSTL to maven project

Tags: java, xml, jsp, maven, jstl

This is my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
       version="3.0">
<display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>startPage.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>DispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>DispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/servlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and startPage.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
```

but when I trying to open page, I recieve exception:

HTTP Status 500 - The absolute uri: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application

What is i am doing wrong? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2):

It seems its happening beacause of scope you defined as `<scope>provided</scope>`

remove `<scope>provided</scope>` and give a try

Below is the description for provided scope from [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html)

**provided**

This is much like compile, but indicates you expect the JDK or a container to provide the dependency at runtime. For example, when building a web application for the Java Enterprise Edition, you would set the dependency on the Servlet API and related Java EE APIs to scope provided because the web container provides those classes. This scope is only available on the compilation and test classpath, and is not transitive.

Comment: if I use dependency whitout scope, I have same problem

Comment: Without result. But bow I have 2 exceptions:
HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.startPage_jsp

and previous.

Comment: your classpath might be having  multiple versions of the same library